# change Background image in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i want to load an image as background in the directive. This should happen after an event. For example if the flag is true, the background should be changed.

How is it possible?

```
myApp.directive('imgDir', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            updateMethod: '=',
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            this.changeBackground = function(flag){
              if(flag){
                var url = '/images/pic1.jpg'
                //load pic1 as background            
              }
              else{
                  var url = '/images/pic2.jpg'
                  //load pic2 as background
              }...
});
```

How does the html have to look like? Because the url is defined in the directive.

thx

Comment: what does the attribute `updateMethod` contain?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to change image you can use ng-class and some css rules. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

```
<div ng-class="{'img-1':flag, 'img-2':!flag}"></div>
```

and in your css

```
.img-1 {
    background-image: url('/images/pic1.jpg');
}


.img-2 {
    background-image: url('/images/pic2.jpg');
}
```

At a first glance i'm not even sure your directive would work. If you want to know more about directives and how to make one you should read this: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: The problem is, that I have ng-view and many directives, who should able to change the background-color.

Comment: i don't think it should interfere (as long as you use background-color and background-image instead of just "background" in your css). Try to test it

Comment: by the way: do you want to change the background of a div or the src of an img?

Comment: I display the image as background in the whole page. I have an layout.cshtml an in this I have an ng-view, so I put the <div ng-class> in the layout.cshtml

Comment: But not every directive has access to the flag variable

Comment: if it's in the current scope it should be visibile to ng-class. If ng-class can't see it then other directives might have the same issue. Can you provide a plunkr or at least a link with your page?

Answer (score 1):

the HTML should be like

```
<div img-dir updateMethod="...">
   ...
</div>
```

,following the online official [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). A directive restricted as attribute is written in the opening tag and if the scope specifies another attribute, [it can be added inline](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#directives).

Comment: @Ludevik this answers at the question "How does the html have to look like? ". does not ?

Comment: Could you add some details of why this should work? Code-only answers are not very useful and are subject to deletion.

Comment: @Cristik My answer is not a fix, but simply the corresponding HTML as asked by the OP, following the online official documentation. Everyone knows that a directive restricted as attribute is written like so and if the scope specifies another attribute, it can be added inline.

Comment: @morels that's good info, could you add it to the answer? The idea here is to avoid code-only posts, as they are not very useful to readers that stumble upon this page.